# How to create Random number with special format in Xcode 7 and Swift 2

Tags: swift2, arc4random

I have a problem with coding. I am trying to generate a Random number of 8 digits eg: 12345676 that show the number like this 12 34 56 76. A number of two digits, so a blank space, a number of two digits and other blank space... THANKS,

***The code what I am using is:***

```
NSMutableArray *numbers;

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){ 
float l_bound = 10;      
float h_bound = 99;
float rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*(h_bound-l_bound)+low_bound);

int intRndValue = (int)(rndValue + 0.5);
[numbers addObject: intRndValue]
;}
NSString *result = [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you have to initialize the array

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and you can add only objects to the array rather than scalar types like `int` or `float`.

```
NSString *intRndValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", (rndValue + 0.5)];
```

In Swift 2 you could write

```
var numbers = Array<String>()
let l_bound : UInt32 = 10
let h_bound : UInt32 = 99

for i in 0..<3 {
  let rndValue =  Int(arc4random_uniform(h_bound - l_bound) + l_bound)
  numbers.append("\(rndValue)")
}
let result = numbers.joinWithSeparator(" ")
```